# Saving file information in Spring batch MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a directory having text files. I want to process files and write data into db. I did that by using `MultiResourceItemReader`.

I have a scenario like whenever file is coming, the first step is to save file info, like filename, record count in file in a log table(custom table).

Since i used `MultiResourceItemReader`, It's loading all files once and the code which i wrote is executing once in server startup. I tried with `getCurrentResource()` method but its returning null.

Please refer below code.

**NetFileProcessController.java**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/netProcess")
public class NetFileProcessController {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("netFileParseJob")
    private Job job;

    @GetMapping(path = "/process")
    public @ResponseBody StatusResponse process() throws ServiceException {
        try {
            Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("date", new JobParameter(new Date()));

            jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters(parameters));
            return new StatusResponse(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception", e);
            Throwable rootException = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e);
            String errMessage = rootException.getMessage();
            log.info("Root cause is instance of JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException --> "+(rootException instanceof JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException));
            if(rootException instanceof JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException){
                log.info(errMessage);
                return new StatusResponse(false, "This job has been completed already!");
            } else{
                throw new ServiceException(errMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BatchConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setJobBuilderFactory(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Value("file:${input.files.location}${input.file.pattern}")
    private Resource[] netFileInputs;

    @Value("${net.file.column.names}")
    private String netFilecolumnNames;

    @Value("${net.file.column.lengths}")
    private String netFileColumnLengths;


    @Autowired
    NetFileInfoTasklet netFileInfoTasklet;

    @Autowired
    NetFlatFileProcessor netFlatFileProcessor;

    @Autowired
    NetFlatFileWriter netFlatFileWriter;

    @Bean
    public Job netFileParseJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("netFileParseJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(netFileStep())
                .build();
    }

    public Step netFileStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("netFileStep")
                .<NetDetailsDTO, NetDetailsDTO>chunk(1)
                .reader(new NetFlatFileReader(netFileInputs, netFilecolumnNames, netFileColumnLengths))
                .processor(netFlatFileProcessor)
                .writer(netFlatFileWriter)
                .build();
    }

}
```

**NetFlatFileReader.java**

```
    @Slf4j
    public class NetFlatFileReader extends MultiResourceItemReader<NetDetailsDTO> {

        public netFlatFileReader(Resource[] netFileInputs, String netFilecolumnNames, String netFileColumnLengths) {
            setResources(netFileInputs);
            setDelegate(reader(netFilecolumnNames, netFileColumnLengths));
        }

        private FlatFileItemReader<NetDetailsDTO> reader(String netFilecolumnNames, String netFileColumnLengths) {
            FlatFileItemReader<NetDetailsDTO> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
            FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = CommonUtil.fixedLengthTokenizer(netFilecolumnNames, netFileColumnLengths);
            FieldSetMapper<NetDetailsDTO> mapper = createMapper();
            DefaultLineMapper<NetDetailsDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
            lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
            lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(mapper);
            flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
            return flatFileItemReader;
        }

        /*
         * Mapping column data to DTO
        */
        private FieldSetMapper<NetDetailsDTO> createMapper() {
            BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<NetDetailsDTO> mapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
            try {
                mapper.setTargetType(NetDetailsDTO.class);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception in mapping column data to dto ", e);
            }
            return mapper;
        }

    }
```

I am stuck on this scenario, Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `MultiResourceItemReader` is appropriate in your case. I would run a job per file for all the reasons of making one thing do one thing and do it well:

- Your preparatory step will work by design
- It would be easier to run multiple jobs in parallel and improve your file ingestion throughput
- In case of failure, you would only restart the job for the failed file

EDIT: add an example

```
Resource[] netFileInputs = ... // same code that looks for file as currently in your reader
for (Resource netFileInput : netFileInputs) {
    Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("netFileInput", new JobParameter(netFileInput.getFilename()));

    jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters(parameters));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mahmoud Ben Hassine even i also thought the same, but if i have 10 files of same format is it would be preferable to write job to every file

Comment: Yes, you would have a single job definition and 10 job instances. The number of files is really not an issue (even if you have many files), that's the way I would use for the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: In my case, file names are not same always. those may vary. Since, files are receiving from third party and placed in a directory

Comment: That's not an issue (files will always have different names anyway), the file name should be a job parameter to create different job instances.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you use to launch jobs and I will edit the answer accordingly with an example.

Comment: Added an example. No need for a MultiResourceItemReader anymore, a `FlatFileItemReader` is enough.

Comment: Yeah @Mahmoud Ben Hassine. Thank you so much for your help. cheers