# Multiple readers in single job in single step using spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am newbie in spring batch. I have a use case in which, I've to read files from a specific folder and write those files in to DB.

For example, I've a files In folder like this

-company_group
|
-my_company_group.json
-my_company_group_alternate_id.json
-sg_company_group.json
-sg_company_group_alternate_id.json

Note: sg = Singapore, my=Malaysia

Now, I want to read these files In the following order.

- SG files should be read first than my files.
- for each country alternate file should come first.

For example,
sg_company_group_alternate_id.json
sg_company_group.json

And same for the MY files

Currently, I'm reading all files by writing custom `MultiResourcePartitioner` and sorting my files order in the way which I mentioned above.

There will be 1 writer and reader for 1 file.

There will be 1 job.

Now, the problem Is I've a step in which I've a custom partitioner which I mentioned above it gets all file sort it but it goes in to only 1 reader. It will go through one reader for all files. I want multiple readers for all files.

I mean to say,  in 1 job I've a step which loads all files. Now in this step, 1 file get read, write in db repeat for other file in same step.

As per my understanding spring batch do not allow multiple readers in 1 step.

Is there any workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a job instance per file, meaning pass the file as an identifying job parameter. This has at least two major benefits:

- Scaling: you can run multiple jobs in parallel, each job processing a different file
- Fault-tolerance: if a job fails, you only restart the failed job, without affecting other files

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud thanks for the answer. But the problem is my files are not fixed. I mean to say that let's say if I have 5 countries than I'll have 10 files total 2 files for each country. The way you suggested I'll have to make 20 jobs than. If 5 countries prefixed with file than means I have 10 jobs.

Comment: That is not an issue. You can do that selection in the main method and launch jobs as needed according to the criteria of choice. The goal is to make each job work on a distinct data set.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please show me the example

Comment: I've xml based configuration

Comment: You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60719833/5019386

Comment: As you mentioned, I can run jobs parallel for each file. I can't do that in my requirement. Because when 1 file is dumped in db then I'll use some values from dB for second file

Comment: I've seen that you implemented CompositeItemReader but PR not merged. Can I use that configuration

Comment: `I can't do that in my requirement. Because when 1 file is dumped in db then I'll use some values from dB for second file`: those tasks are related, so they could be two steps in the same job.

Comment: Yes, I did that with two steps. Both steps have their own readers and writers. Now, suppose I've two country files means total 4 files. 2 alternate files and 2 other files. Now first step will dump both alternate files and second step will dump other files. But I wanted to first dump 1 alternate file and simple file than again repeat the steps with next files. How can I do that?

Comment: That becomes a design issue, not an implementation issue. How would you do that *without* Spring Batch? Spring Batch is an implementation detail here. You need to design a solution where a job handles distinct input, in order to be able to parallelize workloads and have fault-tolerance.

Comment: You mean in spring batch,  I can't do that?

Comment: No, I mean if you show me how to do that without Spring Batch, I will show you how to do it with Spring Batch. Because I think your problem is a design problem, not an implementation problem.